# how to repeat a string which starts with a number

Tags: r, string

This is my data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1 x Bruit (U)", "1 x Bruit (U) 1 x TAMAN (M)", 
"1 x Bruit (U) 2 x TAMAN (M)", "1 x TAMAN (M) 2 x TAMAN (M)", 
"2 x Bruit (U)"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("BUX1_T10963", 
"BUX1_T10964", "BUX1_T10965"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

I want to get the following output.
basically the place that is repeated after the number, I want it to repeat it one row below

```
1 x Bruit (U)   BUX1_T10963
2 x Bruit (U)   BUX1_T10963
2 x Bruit (U)   BUX1_T10963
1 x Bruit (U)   BUX1_T10964
2 x Bruit (U)   BUX1_T10964
2 x Bruit (U)   BUX1_T10964
2 x Bruit (U)   BUX1_T10964
2 x Bruit (U)   BUX1_T10964
NA              BUX1_T10964
NA              BUX1_T10964
NA              BUX1_T10964
NA              BUX1_T10964
1 x TAMAN (M)   BUX1_T10965
2 x TAMAN (M)   BUX1_T10965
1 x Bruit (U)   BUX1_T10965
1 x TAMAN (M)   BUX1_T10965
1 x Bruit (U)   BUX1_T10965
2 x TAMAN (M)   BUX1_T10965
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The key is to use `separate_rows` and specify the regular expression in the `sep` argument. See this (http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) to learn more about lookahead and lookbehind in regular expression.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  separate_rows(V1, sep = "(?<=\\))\\s(?=[0-9]+)") %>%
  select(names(df))
df2

#               V1          V2
# 1  1 x Bruit (U) BUX1_T10963
# 2  2 x Bruit (U) BUX1_T10963
# 3  2 x Bruit (U) BUX1_T10963
# 4  1 x Bruit (U) BUX1_T10964
# 5  2 x Bruit (U) BUX1_T10964
# 6  2 x Bruit (U) BUX1_T10964
# 7  2 x Bruit (U) BUX1_T10964
# 8  2 x Bruit (U) BUX1_T10964
# 9           <NA> BUX1_T10964
# 10          <NA> BUX1_T10964
# 11          <NA> BUX1_T10964
# 12          <NA> BUX1_T10964
# 13 1 x TAMAN (M) BUX1_T10965
# 14 2 x TAMAN (M) BUX1_T10965
# 15 1 x Bruit (U) BUX1_T10965
# 16 1 x TAMAN (M) BUX1_T10965
# 17 1 x Bruit (U) BUX1_T10965
# 18 2 x TAMAN (M) BUX1_T10965
```